# How to retrive the data in chunks by setting start and end offset using laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to fetch the data in chunks like in first attempt from 1 to 50 records and in second attempt from 51 to 100 records. I saw the laravel documentation about chunk () but there is no provision for the custom offset.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to build something custom here. Using standard [`chunk()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#chunking-results) should really work for you:

```
Model::chunk(50, function ($many) {
    foreach ($many as $one) {
        ....
    }
});
```

**Update**

If you want to send `page` number (like 1, 2, 3) from outside to Laravel, you can use [`skip()` and `take()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset):

```
Model::skip(($page - 1) * 50)->take(50)->get();
```

Comment: but how it would be for second attempt from 51 to 100 records

Comment: `chunk()` will create as much attempts as you need. Just put your logic for `1 to 50`, `51 to 100` and other chunks inside `foreach()`

Comment: but if we are passing 50 to chunk that means it will always bring first fifty records if I am not wrong. how will it identify for next fifty records ?

Comment: No, it will pass 50 at the time automatically. That's exactly what `chunk()` was made for.

Comment: Yeah it's even described this way in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#chunking-results

Comment: I got it . but my requirement is something different. I am using laravel for API purpose so when request comes, the first 50 records will process and send and in next request , the next 50 record will process  and send.

Comment: Why didn't you tell about this in your question? To be able to give you better answer we need more information, however if you just want to send `page` number (like 1, 2, 3) from outside and get only data for this page, please check an updated answer for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Needed to use a big big query with lots of joins on an 192k records table. This is what I did:

The query was something like this:

```php
DB::connection('mysql')
    ->table('table1 as A')
    ->join(
        'table2 as B',
        'A.Provincia',
        '=',
        'B.IdProvincia'
    )
    ->select(
        'A.NoExpediente',
        ...
        'A.FechaCita'            
    )
    ->orderBy('NoExpediente')
    // here goes the offset
    ->chunk(function ($records) use (&$offset) {
        foreach ($records as $record) {
            if ($offset > 0) {
                $offset--;
                continue;
            }
            // do something with $record
        }
    );
```

I know the solution is not ideal, because records are being brought from the db anyway, but it saved me a lot of processing on `// do something with $record` the skipped.